# Need help Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm trying to learn RSpec and writing test for CRUD actions. Here is my controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = current_user.articles.all
    respond_with(@articles)
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @article
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  # GET /articles/new.json
  def new
    @article = current_user.articles.build
    respond_with @article
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
    @article = get_article(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article])
    flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created!" if @article.save
    respond_with(@article, location: articles_path)
  end

  # PUT /articles/1
  # PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    @article = get_article(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully updated."
    end
    respond_with @article
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article = get_article(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    respond_with @article
  end

  private
  def get_article(article_id)
    current_user.articles.find(article_id)
  end
end
```

And my articles rspec:

```
describe ArticlesController do

  def valid_attributes
    {
      :title => "Introducting Node.js",
      :content => "Node.js is an event-driven...."
    }
  end

  let(:article) do
    build(:article, valid_attributes)
  end

  describe "PUT 'update'" do

    before(:each) do
      controller.stub_chain(:current_user, :articles, :build) { article }
    end

    context "success" do
      before(:each) do
        article.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return(true)
        put :update, id: article.id
      end

      it "sets notice" do
        flash[:notice].should eq("Article was successfully updated!")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do

    before(:each) do
      controller.stub_chain(:current_user, :articles, :build) { article }
    end

    context "success" do
      before(:each) do
        article.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
        post :create
      end

      it "sets notice" do
        flash[:notice].should eq("Article was successfully created!")
      end

      it "should redirect to article path" do
        response.should redirect_to(articles_path)
      end
    end

    context "failure" do
      before(:each) do
        article.should_receive(:save).and_return(false).as_null_object
        post :create
      end

      it "assigns @article" do
        assigns(:article).should == article
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My question is when I run rspec on PUT UPDATE test is failed. But POST test is passed. I don't have any idea what is going on. I'm using Rails 3.1.1 with omniauth. I'm not using Devise. Here is the test result. Why? Please help me guys?

```
Failures:

  1) ArticlesController PUT 'update' success sets notice
     Failure/Error: put :update, id: article.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find' for #<Object:0xa3cfd20>
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:61:in `get_article'
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:44:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 24.09 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have Article model.

Comment: I have an Article model. Any idea?

Comment: When I logging on get_article function's current_user.articles's class type is Object. Is it correct?

Comment: What happens if you chain `:create` instead of `:build`?

Comment: (Moving to answer; too long.)

Comment: What ended up being the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing.

When you're stubbing, you're just saying "if this method chain is called, return this." There are two issues with that. 1) the code doesn't ever call `build`, and 2) there's no *actual* associations.

I believe you'd need to stub `current_user.articles` to return an article collection. The problem is that AR associations aren't actual arrays, they're proxies.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161203/mocking-activerecord-relationship-beheavior-in-rspec-tests) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057221/stubbing-chained-queries-in-rails-3-and-rspec) for more details. A regular array won't treat the `find` method like the AR method it really is, and you're not returning a single article.

Since you *have* the article ID, you *could* just return that particular article, but your goal is to return that article from within the user's articles to avoid updating someone else's (I assume).

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552721/testing-has-many-association-with-rspec) may also help, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413543/rspec-testing-association).

In other words, you may want a real user there, with real associated objects, so things like `find` will work w/o hackery.

(I fully recognize this isn't a real answer; I've never done this via stubbing, I've used factories/etc.)